# International Phone number Validation with whitespace

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter validation library...for a international number i am trying to accept a Numeric 15 digits..also white space shud be allowed.. but below does not work for some reason...it does not accept whitespace...

```
          if(isset($data['perfume_int_contact']))
           {
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_int_area_code','Contact Phone Number','trim|required|numeric');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_int_first','Contact Phone Number','trim|required|numeric');
```

i shud be able to enter like : 1234 1234 1234 45678
Should i make my own validation class just for this ? or can i make a callback function using it in the set_rules..? Or make a my own regex? Any inputs appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($data['perfume_int_contact'])) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_int_first', 'Contact Phone Number', 'trim|numeric|required|callback_phone_check');
}

function phone_check($phone_number)
{
    $regex = '/^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{3}$/'; // validates 123 123 1234 123
    if (!preg_match($regex, $phone_number)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('phone_check', 'Phone Number not valid.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a real good stuff for some CI beginners like me...thankyou

Comment: just a small question...what is the meaning of /im' .what is the im?

Comment: @ricardo `i` = ignorecase and `m` = multiline. You can just use `/^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{3}$/`

Comment: @ricardo, what is your input coming and what is the expected output? so we can write the regex according to that.

Comment: my input is 1234 123 1234   and my output is: Contact Phone Number is not a valid number....i am not sure if someone may enter like : 123 1234 12345 12   or 123 1234 456 90888  ..? Even inputting this : 123 123 1234 123  does not work.

Comment: @ricardo, remove `numeric` from validation and check. If the phone number contains space then don't use `numeric`.

Comment: the only difference now i see is that ..your message in the function"Phone Number not Valid" is been displayed. My concern is if i remove numeric then can anyone insert alpha??

Comment: @ricardo they can insert anything but above regex will validate `123 123 1234 123` format, so in case alpha is inserted, it will show the error not valid. but you have to modify the regex according to your needs, the one i write is only for example.

Comment: i tried this directly in the set_rules() -> 'trim|required|regex_match[/^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{3}$/]'); it works but it also accept alpha..

Comment: @ricardo i am sure, the Regex i write will accept only digits with space.

Answer (score 1):

// in form validation rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_int_first', 'Contact Phone Number', 'trim|required|max_length[15]|callback_checkPhone');
```

// callback function

```
  function checkPhone($phoneNumber) {
    $output = preg_match('/[^0-9\s]/', $phoneNumber);
    if (empty($output)) {
      return TRUE;
    } else {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('checkPhone', 'This phone number conatins only numbers & white space');
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but somehow th regaex dont work.. if i enter for example : 123 123 1234 123 gives still an error..